# How to find a value in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a binary tree like the picture below, I want to implement a method called `findNode` to return  the node holding the value entered as a parameter.
For example: `findNode(8)=8`, `findNode(13)=13`.
I tried to modify this code but it didn't working :

```
    class Node {
        Node left, right;
        int value;

        public Node findNode(int value) {
            Node focusNode = root;
            if (focusNode == null) {
                return null;
            }
            while (focusNode.value != value) {
                // If we should search to the left
                if (value < focusNode.value) {
                    // Shift the focus Node to the left child
                    focusNode = focusNode.left;
                } else {
                    // Shift the focus Node to the right child
                    focusNode = focusNode.right;
                }
                return focusNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: tree example]

Comment: The code seems fine. What exactly is not working? Are you sure you've built the correct tree? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Wouldn't this code throw a null pointer when it tries the grab the value from a node in the tree without a node on that side? Like with a left node for the 13, there is nothing there. But your code doesn't check for that before trying to grab the value.

Comment: @TimHunter, Yes he needs to move the `if (focus == null)` inside the while loop

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps.  You can't default to left or right but need to check them explicitly.  The null situation is taken care of by the while loop.

```
    public Node findNode(int value) {
        Node focusNode = root;
        while (focusNode != null) {
            // If we should search to the left
            if (value < focusNode.value) {
                // Shift the focus Node to the left child
                focusNode = focusNode.left;
            } else if (value > focusNode.value) {
                // Shift the focus Node to the right child
                focusNode = focusNode.right;
            } else {
                // Found!!
                return focusNode;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaner approach:

```
   class Node {
        Node left, right;
        int value;

        public static Node findNode(Node current, int value) {
            if (current == null)
                return null;
            if (current.value == value)
                return current;
            if (current.value < value) 
                return findNode(current.left, value);
            else 
                return findNode(current.right, value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Recursion is fun, but it is seldom a "cleaner" approach.  Use iteration when possible as it's usually more efficient and isn't limited by the call stack (at least the way Java implements recursion).

Comment: @WJS When you are dealing with rooted trees that are recursive in nature (each tree has a possibly empty tree on its left and a possibly empty tree on its right), thinking about the problem recursively is definitely the way to go. It's also exactly what most interviewers look for on this sort of stuff, which is the main reason you would be dealing with BSTs anyway.

Comment: *It's also exactly what most interviewers look for on this sort of stuff*.   That doesn't really surprise me at all.  It's the same mentality that drives wanting to use `streams` for everything.

Answer (score 0):

your root is either not defined or null every time.
below code would work as expected.

```
class Node
{
    int value;
    Node left, right;

    public Node(int item)
    {
        value = item;
        left = right = null;
    }
}


public class BinaryTree {
    Node root;

    public Node findNode(int value) {
        Node focusNode = root;
        if (focusNode == null){
            return null;
        }

        while (focusNode.value!= value) {

            // If we should search to the left

            if (value< focusNode.value) {

                // Shift the focus Node to the left child

                focusNode = focusNode.left;

            } else {

// Shift the focus Node to the right child

                focusNode = focusNode.right;

            }


        }

        return focusNode;

    }
```

Comment: The code you have here will suffer from a NullPointerException when it tries to grab the value from a sub-node if a node doesn't have a sub-node on both sides. So trying to grab the value `12` for example will throw the exception.